# Как в django в шаблоне получить текст ошибки для конкретного поля?

Tags: django

Массив ошибок передаю вот так:

```
def admin_users_create(request):
args = {}
if request.POST:
    newuser_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if newuser_form.is_valid():
        newuser_form.save()
        return redirect('/admin/users/')
    else:
        args['errors'] = newuser_form.errors.as_data()
return render_to_response('admin/users_create.html', args)
```

Но как в шаблоне получить текст ошибки для конкретного поля?
Допустим под полем email вывести текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

у каждого поля есть атрибут `errors`:

```
newuser_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
newuser_form['my_field'].errors  # ['This field is required.']
```